# Push Sitecore branch sorting to content

Tags: templates, branch, sitecore, sitecore-workflow

I am trying to change the sort order of some of the content on my pages in Sitecore. The initial order was set up by a branch template, and now I want to modify it.

Modifying the content tab itself reorders the items (using the sort buttons on the shell), but when I modify the branch and publish, it doesn't update the content files' order.

I was wondering if there was a way to push the branch sorting onto the content, without having to modify each content page individually, since there are a lot of pages.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Changes in branch templates do not reflect on items that are created with them. So I'm afraid you will need some custom code to push those changes on to existing items.

Comment: That's what I feared. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it programmatically by getting the sortorder field value of each branch item and applying to your content tree accordingly.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I looped through each item and applied each sortorder as I went.